# How do I print While Loop?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

Im trying to print the objects in my Array 'ana' but I keep getting a number 2 after the contents are printed. How do I remove the number 2?

```
var ana = ["I", "Love", "my mother"]; 

var a =  0;

mother = ana.length;

while(a < mother) {
console.log(ana[a]);
a++;  
};
```

Logs:

I
Love
my mother
2

Comment: What browser are you using?  It's not displaying the number 2.  It seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be printing 2 somewhere else after this loop, your code will only print 'I Love my mother'.. also, there shouldn't be any `;` at the end of while loop.

**[See the demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/enqg6fng/)**

Comment: Thank you for that information!!! I voted you up but I guess you must have 15 reputation to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry. This is your interpreter behavior. Your code is not actually printing 2. You are seeing 2 because your javascript interpreter prints the value of last assigned value.

In your code, `a++;` executed in the last loop will return 2(because x++ returns x and then increments it) in the last loop thereby the return value of your whole expression is 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the `a++` inside `console.log` to stop showing it. Like this

`console.log(ana[a++]);`

The value 2 was getting printed as the return value of your code, which is the last value that `a` gets.

Comment: Wow, didnt think of that. Thank you for that!! I cant vote up because I still dont have 15 reputation.